# What does GoDaddy do with their expiring domains that were registered before 2005?

Tags: domains, godaddy, expired-domains

In https://godaddy.com/help/bid-on-expiring-domains-893, GoDaddy say:

> If a domain name registered with us after May 2, 2005 expires, we automatically list it for auction on GoDaddy Auctions® 25 days later. You can bid on any expiring domain name listed at GoDaddy Auctions.

They don't explain what happens with domains registered before 2005. Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Any of such domain has been renewed at least once since then and at renew time there may have been new conditions to accept that basically enforce the same things. But otherwise, did you ask them as first step?

Comment: I was not aware of such a rule, and I have bought name in auctions from them that are old, sometimes as old as 1995. But it could be names that were originally registered somewhere else and transferred to GD at some point.